# Laravel 5.4 Query Builder WHERE NOT IN with multiple WHERE

Tags: laravel-5.4

```
select users.id, users.nickname, users.comment from users 
where users.id <> '.$userId.' and users.id NOT IN
(SELECT friends.friend_id from friends WHERE friends.user_id = '.$userId.')
```

I have followed Laravel Query Builder WHERE NOT IN and converted my query like this

```
 $userId = 1;
 $friend = DB::table('users')
                ->select('users.id, users.nickname, users.comment')
                ->where('users.id', '!=', $userId)
                ->whereNotIn('users.id', function($query){
                    $query->select('friends.friend_id')
                          ->from('friends')
                          ->where('friends.user_id', '=', $userId);
                })->paginate($limit);
```

Undefined variable: userId : ->where('friends.user_id', '=', $userId);

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the variable to the anonymous function using `use`.

`->whereNotIn('users.id', function($query) use ($userId) {`